# How to display all model fields with ModelSerializer?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**models.py**:

```
class Car():
    producer = models.ForeignKey(Producer, blank=True, null=True,)
    color = models.CharField()
    car_model = models.CharField()
    doors = models.CharField()
```

**serializers.py**:

```
class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = Car._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

So, here I want to use all fields. But I have an error:

**Field name `producer_id` is not valid for model `Car`.**

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please include the traceback for this error in your question?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

According to the [Django REST Framework's Documentation on ModelSerializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer):

> By default, all the model fields on the class will be mapped to a corresponding serializer fields.

This is different than [Django's ModelForms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/), which requires you to [specify the special attribute `'__all__'`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use) to utilize all model fields. Therefore, all that is necessary is to declare the model.

```
class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
```

### Update (for versions >= 3.5)

The behaviour described above was deprecated in version 3.3, and forbidden since version 3.5.

[It is now mandatory](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.5-announcement/#modelserializer-fields-and-exclude) to use the special attribute `'__all__'` to use all fields in the Django REST Framework, same as Django Forms:

> Failing to set either fields or exclude raised a pending deprecation warning in version 3.3 and raised a deprecation warning in 3.4. Its usage is now mandatory.

So now it must be:

```
class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: how to add 1 more field to all fields of model?

Comment: @Anuj `fields = (*[f.name for f in MyModel._meta.get_fields()], "another_field")

Answer (score 9):

You could use `fields = '__all__'` to get all your fields or you could specify if you want a limited number of fields to be returned. See [documentation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-which-fields-to-include).

But this returns the `id` value for the foreign key field i.e. `producer` in your case. To get all the fields for `producer`, you need to create a serializer class for that too. See [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/).

So your updated **serializers.py** should be:

```
class ProducerSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Producer

class CarSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    producer= ProducerSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('producer', 'color', 'car_model', 'doors', )
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want all fields to be included in the serializer you can use `fields = '__all__'`:

```
class CarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
      class Meta:
           fields = '__all__'
           model = Car
```

But this approach is not recommended. We should always explicitly specify all fields. This is because it gives us control over fields displayed. If we don't want a field's data to be displayed, we can avoid that.

```
 class CarSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
          class Meta:
               fields = ['name', 'color', 'company', 'price', ]
               model = Car
```