# Issues when define a Django Foreign Key from CharField DataType

Tags: json, django, api

i'm new in Django and I am using it for create a small APIrest, the situation is that when defining the application models I got this

```
class Localities(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    field_id = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=50,db_column='field_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'localities'

class Stratigraphy(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    locality = models.ForeignKey(Localities, models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='locality_id')

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'stratigraphy'
```

The model Stratigraphy is related with the model Localities to the chardfield `field_id`
when creating the serializer to create the json with the data i got this

```
class BedSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stratigraphy
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

when I try the api with postman it shows me [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3s5k.png)

```
class BedSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stratigraphy
        fields = ('id','locality')
```

but if I remove the depth attribute it shows me [the following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6u3l.png)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Django REST Framework's Documentation on ModelSerializers: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer

By default, all the model fields on the class will be mapped to a corresponding serializer fields.

This is different than Django's ModelForms, which requires you to specify the special attribute `'__all__'` to utilize all model fields. Therefore, all that is necessary is to declare the model.

```
class BedSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stratigraphy
        depth = 1
```

Update (for versions >= 3.5)
The behaviour described above was deprecated in version 3.3, and forbidden since version 3.5.

It is now mandatory to use the special attribute '**all**' to use all fields in the Django REST Framework, same as Django Forms:

Failing to set either fields or exclude raised a pending deprecation warning in version 3.3 and raised a deprecation warning in 3.4. Its usage is now mandatory.

So now it must be:

class BedSerializer(ModelSerializer):

```
class Meta:
    model = Stratigraphy
    fields = '__all__'
    depth = 1
```

Answer inspired by the answer to this topic:
[All fields in ModelSerializer django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274591/all-fields-in-modelserializer-django-rest-framework)