# How to get all of field names in serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Imagine if I have a `ModelSerializer`.

How can I get all of my field names in `serializer`?

for example:

```
class AnyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = AnyModel
        fields = ['field1`, 'field2', ...]
```

I want something to iterate through all field names, something like:

```
for field in field_names:
    # do stuff here ...
```

Comment: `serializer.fields` and change it's layout as needed.

Comment: it works, thank you. @AhmedI.Elsayed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display all model fields with ModelSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274591/how-to-display-all-model-fields-with-modelserializer)

Comment: No that's something else @luxcem

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by instantiating first an instance of the serializer class:

```
serializer = AnyModelSerializer()
fields = serializer.get_fields().keys()
```