How do I customize Djoser endpoint '/users/me/' to return all custom user fields?
from djoser.serializers import UserCreateSerializer, UserSerializer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(UserSerializer):
    class Meta(UserSerializer.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('id','email','name','phone_number','address')

The endpoint only returns id, email and name. I want it to return all other fields.

Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274591/how-to-display-all-model-fields-with-modelserializer
